# reCAPTCHA wont show [angular2]

Tags: html, typescript, angular, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement googles reCAPTCHA for my Angular2 app using TypeScript.

I tried following the guide [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024), aswell as the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render) but the reCAPTCHA simply doesn't show up.

This is the html;

```
<form *ngIf="showForm" [ngFormModel]="form" (submit)="onSubmit(email.fromName, email.fromEmail, email.message)">
<div class="wrapper">
  <label for="msg">Message</label>
  <br/>
  <textarea required type="text" [(ngModel)]="email.message" placeholder="Description"  ngControl="msgCtrl"></textarea>
  <div class="msgError" *ngIf="msgCtrl.dirty && !msgCtrl.valid">
    <div *ngIf="msgCtrl.errors.minlength" class="formError">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Your message needs to be longer.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contactInfo">
    <h3>Please supply your contact info here</h3>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <br/>
    <input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="email.fromEmail" placeholder="Your mail" ngControl="emailCtrl"/>
    <div class="emailError" *ngIf="emailCtrl.dirty && !emailCtrl.valid">
    <div *ngIf="emailCtrl.errors.isInCorrectEmail" class="formError">
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Invalid format.
    </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <br/>
    <input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="email.fromName" placeholder="Your name" ngControl="nameCtrl"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttonArea">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY"></div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
    <div class="formError" *ngIf="error === true" role="alert">
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Couldn't send.
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried placing the line

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY"></div>
```

In different areas of the code (in and outside of pretty much all of  the divs) just to see if it would appear at all.

I am importing the script in an index.html file where i import all my other scripts whom work fine.

Thankful for help!

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr? I guess that it's a problem regarding view encapsulation...

Comment: You could try this encapsulation in your component definition: `ViewEncapsulation.Node`. See this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewEncapsulation-enum.html.

Comment: I made a plunkr which was only slightly modified (just importing the script 'localy' in my html file instead of the index.html, so that i didnt have to mimick our projects structure for a simple example) and it actually showed. I'm looking into it. Thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome! Do you want me to have a look at your plunkr?

Comment: Sure, [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/PwvM8qmXleuv3lk1bsVV?p=preview) . I didn't add the email-service.ts since it shouldnt have anything to do with it. And i have yet to implement the actual functionality of the reCAPTCHA (im just trying to get it to show).

Comment: You try to use Angular2 like `ngIf` and `ngModel` in the `index.html` file. Is it normal?

Comment: I actually just pasted from my contact.html -> plunkr's index.html. Could that be a problem?